# Are @ManagedBeans obsolete in JavaEE6 because of @Named in CDI/Weld?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss-weld

Because of CDI (and its implementation Weld), every POJO in JEE6 can be annotated with `@Named`, which makes the POJO accessible to the view.

Does that mean that ManagedBeans are completely obsolete now? 
Or did I miss something where `@ManagedBean` still makes sense?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In short, `@ManagedBean` makes sense for applications that use JSF but do not use JSR 299 (whatever the reason is). Below a longer explanation from Gavin King:

> #### [Re: Comparisons to @ManagedBean annotations in JSF2?](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=58251#327387):
>
> > While looking through the Weld examples, and the older WebBeans
> >     documentation, it looks like a
> >     competitor to the new @ManagedBean JSF
> >     2.0 annotations. Is there any information on when we'd want to use
> >     one over the other?
>
> It's a good question, and I'm not
>   really in full agreement with the
>   answers that have been posted so far.
>
> The new EE Managed Beans specification
>   defines a base component model for
>   Java EE, together with a very basic
>   set of container services (`@Resource`,
>   `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy`).
>
> The idea is that other specifications
>   (beginning with EJB, CDI, JSF and the
>   new Java Interceptors spec) build upon
>   this base component model and layer
>   additional services, for example
>   transaction management, typesafe
>   dependency injection, interceptors. So
>   at this level, the managed beans, CDI,
>   interceptors and EJB specifications
>   all work hand-in-hand and are highly
>   complementary.
>
> Now, the Managed Beans specification
>   is quite open-ended with respect to
>   identifying exactly which classes are
>   managed beans. It does provide the
>   `@ManagedBean` annotation as one
>   mechanism, but it also allows other
>   specifications to define different
>   mechanisms. So, for example:
>
> - The EJB specification says that a class obeying certain programming
>     restrictions with a `@Stateless` or
>     `@Stateful` annotation deployed in an
>     EJB jar is a managed bean.
> - The CDI specification says that any class with an appropriate constructor
>     deployed in a "bean deployment
>     archive" is a managed bean.
>
> Given that EJB and CDI provide
>   arguably more convenient ways to
>   identify a managed bean, you might
>   wonder precisely what `@ManagedBean` is
>   needed for. The answer, as alluded to
>   by Dan, is that if you have CDI
>   available in your environment (for
>   example, if you are using EE6), then
>   `@ManagedBean` is just not really
>   needed. **`@ManagedBean` is really there
>   for use by people who are using JSF2
>   without CDI**.
>
> OTOH, if you do annotate a bean
>   `@ManagedBean`, and you do have CDI in
>   your environment, you can still use
>   CDI to inject stuff into your bean.
>   It's just that the `@ManagedBean`
>   annotation is not *required* in this
>   case.
>
> To summarize, **if you do have CDI
>   available to you, it provides a *far*
>   superior programming model to the
>   `@ManagedBean`/`@ManagedProperty` model
>   that JSF2 inherits from JSF1**. So
>   superior, in fact, that the EE 6 web
>   profile does not require support for
>   `@ManagedProperty` etc. The idea being
>   that you should just use CDI instead.

Comment: While not stated in the question, I read it to assume JSR 299.

Answer (score 15):

You have a choice.  Either use the @ManagedBean from JSF2 to bind beans into your forms, or use the @Named annotation from CDI.  If you plan on only doing JSF, you can stick to @ManagedBean, but if you want to integrate with EJB's, or make use of CDI's @ConversationScoped, then go the CDI route.

Personally I feel the next version of JSF should deprecate the @ManagedBean, and standardize on CDI.  The duality is confusing to newcomers.

Answer (score 10):

CDI has no view scope, because it [doesn't have the notion of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812985/cdi-missing-viewscoped-and-flashscoped), so if you need that scope, CDI in its pure form can't do it. View scope basically means [request scope + being AJAX-ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220407/viewscoped-works-like-requestscoped-why/5220668#5220668). It's **not** a JSF view, like a page named `xyz.xhtml`, even though you see JSF `<f:viewParam>` and the likes. A frequent use case with view-scoped beans is [how to get GET parameters into a such a bean](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters). Also [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id).

Note that CDI rather lives at the EJB/service layer than the JSF/presentation layer. [This blog](http://www.hascode.com/2011/02/creating-a-sample-java-ee-6-blog-application-with-jpa-ejb-cdi-jsf-and-primefaces-on-glassfish/) has a nice overview.

As such `@ManagedBean` cannot be fully replaced by CDI, again if you're using `@ViewScoped` beans - at least not without [extending CDI](http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2010/01/06/porting-the-viewscoped-jsf-annotation-to-cdi/) or using the [Seam 3 Faces module](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/scopes.html#viewscoped). Using view-scoped beans is almost always going to happen when using AJAXed JSF 2-based GUI toolkits like RichFaces, PrimeFaces, IceFaces etc.

Mixing annotations from the wrong Java EE 6 packages *can* get you in trouble unexpectedly, again when using RichFaces or a similar API:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.[Jsf]Scoped
```

are for components used **solely** at the presentation layer, here by RichFaces, PrimeFaces, etc. Some rich components [seem to have problems with CDI-annotated and JSF-annotated helper beans](http://community.jboss.org/thread/173633). If you get strange behavior from your beans (or beans that seem to do nothing) the wrong mix of annotations might be the cause.

Mixing JSF and CDI, like

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.bean.[Jsf]Scoped
```

is possible and works in most cases when referenced from JSF pages, however there are some little-known issues/drawbacks, e.g. when [using a JSF scope which CDI doesn't have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723417/getting-a-get-request-param-into-an-viewscoped-bean):

> Also the combination `@Named @ViewScoped` won't work as intended. The JSF-specific `@ViewScoped` works in combination with JSF-specific `@ManagedBean` only. Your CDI-specific `@Named` will behave like `@RequestScoped` this way. Either use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named` or use CDI-specific `@ConversationScoped` instead of `@ViewScoped`.

Then

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.bean.[Cdi]Scoped
```

can be used for CDI beans directly referenced from your JSF pages AFAIK. I haven't had any problems with the above combinations so far, so you could consider `@ManagedBean` obsolete here.

What's left is the service layer, here mostly transactional EJB service beans declared as

```
@javax.ejb.*
```

mostly @javax.ejb.Stateless. You can even annotate and use [EJBs directly from JSF pages](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_1_killed_the) - though I'm not sure if this design is desirable. To reference (inject) any components annotated with @javax.ejb.*, e.g. `@Stateless`, prefer `@Inject` over `@EJB` [as described here](http://www.germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html). (Probably an ancestor of this answer...)

Finally, a very nice overview of Java EE 6 annotations can be found here:
http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~rennie/javaEEReferenceSheet.html

**Note**: the above info is not from an expert, but simply my own take/sight from a newcomers perspective on this **ridiculously confusing Java EE 6 annotations spaghetti**. More insight has yet to be developed. I hope this answer can endure to be a general, practical answer to this confusion - even though it has gone a little overboard in the context of the original question.

Comment: you posted a reply comment which was half decent but then some force took over and you changed it into an insane blob.People are suggesting CDI is replacement over @managed. Question is clear but comparing apples with oranages.

Comment: Yes, kind of. I still have to be convinced how CDI is such a replacement. In the meantime, newcomers are looking for solutions, not 'spec-babble'. They (I) need some help to decide which annotations to use in which situation to get things going. IMHO

Comment: I think you exactly answered the question as narrowly as possible.  In fact, I would like 500 *more* words on this subject...

Comment: CDI can perfectly make use of the JSV @ViewScoped annotation via a CDI Extension. See

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/JSF+Usage

Just use the javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped _without_ the ManagedBean annotation, and CODI will manage it for you (in CDI).

Comment: Or Seam 3 Faces. Or any equivalent.

Comment: I think OmniFaces is also a great tool as it has its own `@ViewScope` that CDI understands and works pretty well!

Answer (score 7):

As i Just read in the [Weld Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/pdf/weld-reference.pdf) (p. 12), @ManagedBean is now superflous:

> You can explicitly declare a managed
>   bean by annotating the bean class
>   @ManagedBean, but in CDI you don't
>   need to. According to the
>   specification, the CDI container
>   treats any class that satisfies the
>   following conditions as a managed
>   bean:
>
> - It is not a non-static inner class. It is a concrete class, or is
>     annotated @Decorator.
> - It is not annotated with an EJB component-defining annotation or
>     declared as an EJB bean class in
>     ejb-jar.xml.
> - It does not implement javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension.
> - It has an appropriate constructor—either:
> - the class has a constructor with no parameters, or
> - the class declares a constructor annotated @Inject.