# Why is my @ViewScoped bean being referenced on browser refresh after bean destroyed and POST to render new page?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, cdi, omnifaces, view-scope

First of all, I am using OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped which was recently added to and released in OmniFaces 1.6. I am very pleased to use OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped in my app, but I have a question.

I noticed some NullPointerException's in my (TomEE 1.6 snapshot) server log, and I even experienced the NullPointerException's while testing pages that use/reference beans marked with OmniFaces CDI @ViewScoped. The NullPointerException's occur when I typically do something similar to the following:

(1) 'Render' a page that references/uses CDI @ViewScoped bean.

(2) Click a (PrimeFaces) commandButton/Link (below) which exists the 'view', and the commandButton/Link action="..." is responsible for destroying the @ViewScoped bean.

```
<p:commandButton value="Exit Messenger"
                 action="#{messengerBean.exitMessenger()}"
                 ajax="false"/>
```

and

```
public String exitMessenger() {
    pageNavigationController.setToBlankPage();
    // to destroy this CDI @ViewScoped bean
    return "index.xhtml";
}
```

(3) Immediately after step #2 above, myself or enduser does a 'browser refresh' (F5 key in Google Chrome), and for some/whatever reason, the CDI @ViewScoped bean (referenced by step #1 above) is reconstructed without the bean being reconstructed...correctly, since an actionListener=#{viewScopedBean.methodToPrepareStep1View()} or action="#{viewScopedBean.methodToPrepareStep1View()}" is 'not' invoked by the 'browser refresh' button/request.

(4) So, the @ViewScoped bean members are 'null' and NullPointerException's are being raised when users 'unexpectedly' press F5 or do a 'browser refresh'.

NOTE: state saving = server and (HTTP) Filter is instructing browser 'not' to cache the jsf/xhtml page via the following (which I learned from BalusC, long time ago, here on stackoverflow.com):

```
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

Also, I read the following other/related posts:

[Is JSF 2.0 View Scope back-button safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930900/is-jsf-2-0-view-scope-back-button-safe)

[What scope to use in JSF 2.0 for Wizard pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896813/what-scope-to-use-in-jsf-2-0-for-wizard-pattern)

[ViewScoped works like RequestScoped - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220407/viewscoped-works-like-requestscoped-why)

[jsf clearing the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051842/jsf-clearing-the-form)

Is this due to bad design on my part (as 2-year-old JSF developer)?

Do I need to test all of my xhtml pages which reference CDI @ViewScoped beans, and repeat the steps that I listed above, and then just handle NullPointerException everywhere in my code...that is caused by 'browser refresh'? Is this the only way to resolve this or is there a better more-recommended way of handling (or avoiding) NullPointerException's caused by browser refresh after CDI @ViewScoped bean destroyed?

Please advise/confirm. Thanks.

EDIT: (2) above with 'correct' description and code that helps to replicate this issue.

Comment: The `<ui:include src>` on a view scoped bean requires some trickery as it's also invoked during view build time and a change during postback requires a full rebuild of the view. First of all, are you able to exclude the OmniFaces CDI `@ViewScoped` from being the cause by recreating the same problem with standard JSF `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: I probably can. I used ViewScoped many months/moons ago after reading some of your answers/posts here on stackoverflow (when I first started developing JSF), and then this response of yours 'just reminded' me that I had issues with JSF ViewScoped because of my usage of ui:include src="#{viewScopedBean.prepareView...()}", and I reverted to JSF SessionScoped, and then to CDI SessionScoped. When OmniFaces added CDI ViewScoped, i wanted to revert back to ViewScoped, (lol), but now I'm having this issue. I tried PRG, but then that felt to JSF 1.2'ish, so I got rid of that from the app. :)

Comment: You mentioned 'trickery' for this (type of) situation/scenario/issue. Sounds like something good to add to OmniFaces...to handle this...to make JSF developer's life...much much much easier! big :)

Comment: I considered it, but I gave up. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680192/dynamic-ajax-navigation-with-uiinclude/ In the meanwhile I've however learnt some new lessons, I might want to revisit this approach.

Comment: Interesting. taking a look at it now. FYI, I am using OmniFaces enableRestorableView component and the commandButton/Link/menuitem's are ajax="false". does your recommended solution/workaround apply to ajax="false", too?

Comment: something (another question) came to mind... if I replace some ViewScoped bean references with RequestScoped bean references, e.g. ui:include src=#{requestScopedBean.methodWhichWillInvokeViewScopedBean()}, is this also a possible solution/workaround?

Comment: @BalusC I know it does not 'answer' this question, but i have already resolved the 2 or 3 different exceptions caused by repeating the steps, mentioned earlier, to replicate this issue. Basically, I modified PostConstruct to make sure variables are initialized, I added 'beanMember != null' to PreDestroy, and I replaced ui:include src="#{viewScopedBean.page}" with src=#{requestScopedBean.page}, and requestScopedBean.page (getter method) referenced viewScopedBean.page. ViewScoped PostConstruct and PreDestroy are executed on browser refresh, and I don't have exceptions anymore, 'now'. :)

Comment: @BalusC if you have an answer for this behavior, I will definitely mark your answer as checked. I had to revert to 'trickery' (as you mentioned earlier).  I do that a lot while developing JSF, but of course, I don't do trickery as good as you do, BalusC. :)

Comment: Please see EDIT (2) above...to successfully duplicate the issues, which prompted me to ask this question.