# @Named behaving different from @ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, cdi

I'm currently migrating a project from JBoss 4.2.2 to JBoss 6.0.0 and I'm also adding Dependency Injection with CDI and migrate from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0. I added a beans.xml file to both the ejb-package, as well as the war-package.

Now I have a xhtml page that uses the managed bean `LoginBean.java`. The beans had been configured in the faces-config.xml like this:

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Sample description</description>
    <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.sample.managedbeans.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

So, at first I removed above configuration and added `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` to the class itself. Because I wanted to add CDI to the project, I changed `@ManagedBean` to `@Named` (in relation to [question 2930889](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930889/are-managedbeans-obsolete-in-javaee6-because-of-named-in-cdi-weld)).

Now when I submit the form of the corresponding xhtml, the fields *username* and *password* (used in the JSP as `#{loginBean.username}` ) are null. When I change back to `@ManagedBean`, it works fine.

Am I missing something here?

Kind regards,
  Sebastian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two `@SessionScoped` annotations now in ee6, `@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` which comes from the jsf 2 spec and only works together with `@ManagedBean` and then there is `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` from cdi. My guess is that you are using the jsf annotation, which is ignored by cdi, and so cdi creates a new instance of your bean.

Comment: Holy cow. That's nasty. Didn't try it yet, but you are right. Used the wrong namespace.