# Every time I make an Ajax request in JSF2 I am getting a new session bean,why?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

Hi I am getting a new session bean for every ajax request made to this Bean... Can any of you tell me why ?

```
...... imports ......
@Named(value = "userController")
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {

private User current;
private DataModel items = null;
@EJB
private br.com.cflex.itm.dataaccess.UserFacade ejbFacade;
private PaginationHelper pagination;
private int selectedItemIndex;

public UserController() {
}

public Collection<Project> getMyProjectList(){
    String login = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
    User u = ejbFacade.getUserFromLogin(login);
    return u.getProjectCollection();
}    

public User getSelected() {               
    if (current == null) {
        current = new User();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
} 
....... rest of class ....
```

Every time I make this request I am getting a new of this SessionBean I for as far as I know I should be getting the same guy over and over again.

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
      <h:form>
       <h:outputText value="#{bundle.FirstName}"/>                                
         <h:inputText id="name" value="#{userController.selected.name}">
          <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="name" render="out" />
<!--       <f:ajax event="keyup" render="out"/>-->
           </h:inputText>
           <p>
            <h:commandButton value="add"></h:commandButton>      
            <h:outputText id="out" value="#{userController.selected.name}"/>
           </p>
      </h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: For the sake of tidyness: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581010/named-behaving-different-from-managedbean (no offense meant, question is highly different from yours)

Comment: none taken... thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if you accidently imported `@SessionScoped` from the [`javax.faces.bean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/SessionScoped.html) package instead of the [`javax.enterprise.context`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) package.

You're using [`@javax.inject.Named`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) annotation, so you should import the scopes from the `javax.enterprise.context` package. The scopes from the `javax.faces.bean` package only works in combination with [`@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) annotation.

A CDI bean without a valid scope will behave like `@RequestScoped`. A JSF bean without a valid scope will behave like `@NoneScoped`.