# JSF session ManagedBean instantiated at each request

Tags: jsf, constructor, javabeans

I have a @ManagedBean in my app, with the @sessionScoped anotation.

The problem is that the public no arg constructor is being called for each request, so my fields are being reseted and my model logic goes to space.

I tried build and clean, reset glassFish, but still the bean constructor get's called at each request.
I also have a faces-config.xml to control the page navigation.

I could solve this by redeclaring the bean inside the faces-config, now it work's...

Any ideas of why that's happening? If i delete the faces-config, the problem persists.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: @Shahzeb: OP is definitely using JSF2. Otherwise the `@ManagedBean` wouldn't be importable on the class nor be constructed on each request at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen if `@SessionScoped` is not of the [`javax.faces.bean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/SessionScoped.html) package, but instead of a completely different API, for example the [`javax.enterprise.context`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) package. Doublecheck your imports and be careful with IDE autocompletion. IDEs tend to sort autosuggestions by package name and thus the `javax.enterprise.context` would appear as 1st option.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
    // ...
}
```

If you aren't using any `javax.faces.bean` scope annotation on a `@ManagedBean`, then the bean will default to [`@NoneScoped`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/NoneScoped.html), which means that it's constructed on every single `#{bean}` EL evaluation.

#### See also:

- [Every time I make an Ajax request in JSF2 I am getting a new session bean,why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687812/every-time-i-make-an-ajax-request-in-jsf2-i-am-getting-a-new-session-bean-why) (the opposite of this problem)
- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

Comment: What is `javax.enterprise.context ` for any way?

Comment: @Shahzeb: that's CDI (to be used with `@Named`, injectable with `@Inject`, etc).

Comment: Ohh! That was exactly the problem...than you very much!             Damn you NetBeans Autocompletion!