# Add items to List in Request Scoped Bean

Tags: jsf, scope, cdi

I have a backing bean as following:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ClientNewBackingBean {

    @Inject
    private ClientFacade facade;
    private Client client;
```

The `Client` class has a `List<Child> childrenList` attribute, among others. I'm able to create a new `Client` when setting the `childrenList` with `new ArrayList()`.

In the view, I have a input text field and an `Add Child` button. The button has the attribute `actionListener=#{clientNewBackingBean.addChild()}` implemented as:

```
public void addChild() {

    if(client.getChildrenList() == null) {
        client.getChildrenList(new ArrayList());
    }

    Child c = new Child("John Doe");

    client.getChildrenList().add(c);
}
```

Everytime the `Add Child` button is clicked, the bean is recreated and the view only shows one John Doe child (due to it being Request scoped, I believe). Is there another way to solve this besides changing the bean scope to Session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were using standard JSF bean management annotation `@ManagedBean`, you could have solved it by just placing the bean in the view scope by [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html).

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClientNewBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ClientFacade facade;

    // ...
```

In CDI, the `@ViewScoped` however doesn't exist, the closest alternative is [`@ConversationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html). You only have to start and stop it yourself.

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class ClientNewBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    // ...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        conversation.begin();
    }

    public String submitAndNavigate() {
        // ...

        conversation.end();
        return "someOtherPage?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

You can also use the CDI extension [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) which will transparently bridge the JSF `@ViewScoped` annotation to work properly together with `@Named`:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ClientNewBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private ClientFacade facade;

    // ...
```

A CODI alternative is to use `@ViewAccessScoped` which lives as long as the subsequent requests reference the very same managed bean, irrespective of the physical view file used.

```
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
public class ClientNewBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private ClientFacade facade;

    // ...
```

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)
- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)

Comment: the lack of `@ViewScoped` in CDI was exactly the problem. I will use the `@ConversationScoped`. Your solution is clean and precise as always. Thanks.

Comment: I set the code as in the given example but when I click `Add Child` it still calls the `@PostConstruct` annotated method again. What am I missing?

Comment: Changed to the MyFaces CODI approach and it works. I'll stick to it.

Comment: MyFaces CODI bridges `@ViewScoped` to CDI. So you don't have to use a different annotation. `@ViewAccessScoped` is a completely different Scope with a different behaviour. CODI Scopes are in 99% the better choice!

Comment: @DarWhi: right, thank you for the correction. I updated the answer.

Comment: @DarWhi how do I use this bridging? Just add the MyFaces CODI dependency (it's a Maven project) and import `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`, or I must import a MyFaces CODI specific class?

Comment: Just the JSF standard annotation, yes.

Comment: I have added the MyFaces CODI dependencies and annotated the bean `@ViewScoped`. Added `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotated methods to the bean. Every time the bean is requested by the view (e.g. commandLink that calls an actionListener method), it behaves like a `@RequestScoped` bean (construct, @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy methods are executed). Any idea whats the problem?

Comment: @DarWhi may better be able to answer this particular issue (he's one of the MyFaces CODI guys, so I assumed his statement to be true). I've myself not used this construct before.

Comment: Good find. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I deleted the previous answer (saying that it was related to the specific implementation) because it's a little more complex than I thought. I'm going to open a new question with the specific issue.

Comment: The problem: to go to the "new client" view, I was using a `<h:commandLink action="new/index.xhtml" actionListener="#{clientNewBackingBean.prepareCreate()}"/>`. The bean was getting created, it's `prepareView()` method got called, destroyed and then created again.

Comment: The solution: The `prepareCreate()` call caused the bean to be created and initiated, then the `action` part kicked in and the navigation destroyed the bean. Any method call from the view would cause the bean to be created again. So I removed the `actionListener` attribute and that's it. Also, I added the right maven pom for MyFaces CODI (myfaces-extcdi-assembly-jsf20 in case some one needs).

Comment: #1 I'm not one of the CODI devs (only a "poweruser")
#2 That's the correct behaviour of `@ViewScoped` (defined in the JSF spec.)
#3 IMHO `@ViewScoped` is only useful for some very rare cases. `@ViewAccessScope` does what you expect

Comment: @DarWhi I'm learning JSF by myself, could you please provide some content on the difference between CODI's `@ViewAccessScope` and `@ViewScoped`? Up there you said that `@ViewAccessScope` "is a completely different Scope with a different behaviour" and got me confused saying that `@ViewScoped` is only for rare cases.

Comment: `@ViewScoped` is specified by the JSF spec. and is bound to one view. You can't use the stored values on a different page -> if you have a page and have lots of AJAX requests to the same page and you don't need the values on the next page, you should use it.
`@ViewAccessScoped` is a custom CDI scope invented by CODI. Your beans exist for the _next_ logical (not HTTP - could be 2 HTTP requests if you trigger a nav. with a redirect) request as long as they get touched during a logical request. If needed you can also destroy them earlier (manually).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF 2, you should use `ViewScoped` bean.