# JBoss AS 7.1.1 dependency injection in JSF app

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, primefaces

It looks like the dependency is not beeing injected, is there anything wrong with my code?

Page

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="centralizado" id="cdt" var="c" value="#{indexBean.getCampanhas()}">
```

IndexBean

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean {
    @Inject
    private GerenciaContas contas;
    @Inject
    private GerenciaCampanhas campanhas;
    @Inject
    private Conversor conv;

    public List<Campaign> getCampanhas() throws Exception {
        return campanhas.getTodasCampanhas();
    }

    public GerenciaContas getContas() {
        return contas;
    }

    public Conversor getConversor() {
        return conv;
    }

}
```

One of the classes I use:

```
public class GerenciaCampanhas 
{
    public List<Campaign> getTodasCampanhas() throws Exception {
              //ordinary code
    }
}
```

Am I missing any Annotation in my Conversor class ?
I am getting a NullPointerException because "GerenciaCampanhas campanhas" is null then calling the method getCampanhas() in my indexBean
Thanks

Comment: Which are the packages of `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped`?

Comment: import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

Comment: What is `GerenciaCampanhas` exactly (CDI, EJB, Spring, ManagedBean)? If you use CDI, you need an empty file named `beans.xml` in your META-INF folder in order to enable CDI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Replace `@ManagedBean` by `@Named` - you can't use `@Inject` in JSF managed beans (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces)
2. Choose other scope than `@ViewScoped` - there's no such scope for CDI managed beans;
3. Make sure you have the `beans.xml` file in your ejb's META-INF folder (if it's an enterprise project, it goes under the META-INF in your ejb project and under WEB-INF in your web project).

Like:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import xxxx.GerenciaContas;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private GerenciaContas contas;
```

If you still need to use `@ViewScoped` add MyFaces CODI extensions to you project as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158885/add-items-to-list-in-request-scoped-bean). Greetings from Brazil =).

Comment: -1: you're wrong. You can inject EJB's in JSF 2 just by using the `@EJB` annotation before declaring the EJB attribute. No need to use CDI at all.

Comment: As stated from the question, we're not sure if OP really wanted to use `@Inject` or if he/she's in learning phase and doing some experiments. Another option could be to convert the `GerenciaCampanhas` (and the other business logic classes) into EJB's by adding the `@Stateless` annotation to them, with this the `@ManagedBean` and `@ViewScoped` annotations will remain in the managed bean definition.

Comment: Ok @LuiggiMendonza, I'm a newbie here and I'm still learning to answer questions. I've changed item 1 text and added a question on this. OP marked as answered so I understand the answer fit his needs. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Point 2 is strange. EJBs does not support any of those JSF/CDI scopes anyway. Aren't you mixing EJBs (`@Stateless`/`@Stateful` classes) with CDI managed beans (`@Named` classes)?

Comment: You're right @BalusC, sometimes I mix up definitions. Edited the answer.