# MyFaces CODI instantiates beans twice

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, myfaces, codi

I'm migrating a JSF 2.1 application to CDI. To be able to use the `@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` annotation, I'm trying to use MyFaces CODI, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158885/add-items-to-list-in-request-scoped-bean/14158970#14158970).

The application seems to be working as expected, but I noticed by logging that the constructor of each of my `@Named` beans is called twice when I first access it. However, their `init()` methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` are only executed once.

When those beans are used for the second or nth time, their constructor is only called once as normally expected.

It doesn't happen as soon as I remove the MyFaces CODI jars from my app, so I'm sure it is caused by it.

Is this a normal behaviour, and if so, why? Does it have an impact on performance or could this cause any problem?

I'm feeling this could be linked with a proxy creation, but it's not 100% clear in my mind so I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

My configuration:

- JSF 2.1
- Mojarra 2.1.6
- MyFaces CODI 1.0.5 (tested with full bundle or core + JSF 2.0+)
- (unrelated: Primefaces 3.5 and Omnifaces 1.5)
- Glassfish 3.1.2, also tested on Jboss EAP 6.0 with the same results

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has everything to do with proxy creation and it is the expected behavior with CDI. See this https://community.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies, as you could probably find other explanations that say the same thing.

But as to why it happens with @javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped and CODI, that's because CODI activates a CDI extension, that scans for beans with the JSF ViewScope and replaces it at runtime with their own CDI based implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, I will read it with great interest.

Answer (score 0):

@rdcrng is correct.

With CDI you need @PostConstruct methods instead.