# Instance null after injecting @SessionScoped CDI bean into a JSF @ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, cdi, inject

I have :
- Repository Class:

```
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        TypedQuery<Employee> qu = entityManager.createQuery("select * from Employee", Employee.class);
        List<Employee> emp2 = qu.getResultList();
        return emp2;
    }
}
```

and

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorldBean")
public class HelloWorldBean {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeRepository employeerepo;
    public String getMsg() {
        return "Hallo";
    }
    public String getEmployees() {
        return String.valueOf(employeerepo.getEmployees().size());
    }
}
```

and a JSF Page:

```
<h:head>
    <title>JavaCodeGeeks</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    - Message : <h:outputText value="#{helloWorldBean.msg}" />
    - Employee count : <h:outputText value="#{helloWorldBean.employees}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

I have an `beans.xml` in my META-INF Folder (src\META-INF) without special configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
  bean-discovery-mode="all" version="1.1">
</beans>
```

Problem:

Page throws nullpointer exception, because the EmployeeRepository is not injected in the HelloWorldBean.

What to do to be able to inject Instances of classes in my case ?

Comment: Which version of CDI are you using?

Comment: javaee-api-6.0.jar . beans_1_1.xsd. My beans.xml is in src\META-INF\

Comment: Ok, beans_1_1 is CDI 1.1. Do you have `bean-discovery-mode` property in beans.xml? Which is the value? By the way, CDI 1.1 is Java EE 7 while you have Java EE 6 api...

Comment: I have added the content of beans.xml to the question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which application server or servlet container (and version) are you using?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using CDI, you should not be using `@ManagedBean` (which is a JSF annotation). While I have actually seen this working, most implementations will not allow you to inject a CDI bean into a classic JSF bean.

To allow for CDI injection in JSF beans, the CDI specification allows you to define JSF backing beans by specifying the `@Named` annotation in combination with a scope (`@RequestScoped`, `@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`, `@SessionScoped` and `@ApplicationScoped`).

So in summary, the following piece of code should solve your problem,

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorldBean {
    @Inject
    private EmployeeRepository employeerepo;
    public String getMsg() {
        return "Hallo";
    }

    public String getEmployees() {
        return String.valueOf(employeerepo.getEmployees().size());
    }
}
```

You can also read up further on the topic via some old Q/A's here on the site,

[How to inject a CDI Bean in a ManagedBean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341877/how-to-inject-a-cdi-bean-in-a-managedbean)

[@ManagedProperty does not work in a CDI managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390792/managedproperty-does-not-work-in-a-cdi-managed-bean)

[CDI beans injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792974/cdi-beans-injection)

Comment: Thanks for helping. With the new code it seems that the xhtml does not find my bean. The HelloWorldBean is not called. Any help ?

Comment: @mcflysoft Make sure you call `helloWorldBean` and not `HelloWorldBean`. Any class name will get a variable with camel-case notation (unless you explicitly specify what to name it). Also make sure you run your application in an environment that fully supports CDI. Tomcat 7 doesn't out of the box and needs additional configuration. I would suggest you look into a full fledged JavaEE server with up-to-date implementations of JavaEE / JakartaEE like Payara, GlassFish or WildFly.

Comment: Or TomEE ;-) Yes, effectively this is a new question fpr which there are several related q/an stackoverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje Is TomEE fully up to date these days? Last time I tried it I had to muck around and do a lot of extra configuraiton steps to get everything working properly.

Comment: Last time I tried it worked sort of ok, but that was just a try without jms but with cdi, jsf, ejb AND 1.5 years ago. I usually use Wildfly.