# Use JSF beans in Java EE 7

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

In Java EE 6 one of the reasons I stuck with the `@ManagedBean` was `@ViewScoped`. Now in Java EE 7 this is available for @Named beans also.

Will I miss out on anything if going with `@Named` in new apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IIRC, the JSF managed beans are pretty much deprecated in JSF 2.2 (Java EE 7).

Comment: They are indeed effectively deprecated. Unfortunately no 'official' deprecation has been done yet, but the spec lead did mention the intention was there.

Answer (score 0):

In blog post ["You should not have any other @ManagedBean beside @Named."](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/04/you-should-not-have-any-other.html) Markus Eisele states:

> The drawback is, you will probably lose the ability to run on very
>   lightweight Java appserver which do not conform to one of the defined
>   profiles and can't provide DI/CDI features.

Other than that i did not find any arguments to stick with `@ManagedBean`

which also is pretty much stated in Pascal's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930889/are-managedbeans-obsolete-in-javaee6-because-of-named-in-cdi-weld):