# CDI feature in WLP is not working

Tags: cdi, websphere-liberty

I have enabled cdi-1.0 in project facet along with beans.xml and added same feature in WLP for my JSF/EJB application to use @Inject from ManagedBean/controller. But it gives me below runntime errors that leads to "Context root failure" as result no page is loading. I am providing below the code snippets. Mesaage/trace.log and FFDC log. Please suggest what could be the reason? thanks in advance.

DocumentViewController.java

```
    @ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DocumentViewController extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private DocumentControllerLocal documentController = null;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4113377542725857282L;
    /**
     * 
     */

    private List<Document> docs;
    private List<Document> filteredDocs;
    private String searchInput;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
.............
```

Message.log

```
[7/10/16 16:06:00:077 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:077 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:077 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:077 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:077 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARRedirect:[/gsar/abb/abb_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_framework_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_overview.xhtml, /gsar/abb/gda_sbb_table_view.xhtml, /gsar/abb/primary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/secondary_abb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_details.xhtml, /gsar/abb/sbb_integration_considerations.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/doc_view_type.xhtml, /gsar/general_view/doc_type_models/document_type.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_client_first.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_1.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook_2.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/about_playbook.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line.xhtml, /gsar/domain_views/organization/view_service_line_component.xhtml]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/imageServlet/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[ImageServlet:[/imageServlet/*]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/faces/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Faces Servlet:[*.faces, /faces/*, *.xhtml, /gsar/*]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Faces Servlet:[*.faces, /faces/*, *.xhtml, /gsar/*]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:092 IST] 00000047 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp createServletWrappers SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/gsar/login/login_check, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[GSARLogin:[/gsar/login/login_check]], application-->GSAR-WebEAR.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:202 IST] 00000047 WebContainerL I   OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
[7/10/16 16:06:00:638 IST] 00000047 InjectionTarg W   CWNEN0057W: The com.ibm.gsar.dao.FwbCatDAO.fwbController injection target must not be declared static.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:638 IST] 00000047 InjectionTarg W   CWNEN0057W: The com.ibm.gsar.dao.GsspServiceDAO.gsspController injection target must not be declared static.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:654 IST] 00000047 InjectionTarg W   CWNEN0057W: The com.ibm.gsar.dao.PageCommentDAO.pageCommentController injection target must not be declared static.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:654 IST] 00000047 InjectionTarg W   CWNEN0057W: The com.ibm.gsar.dao.SearchDAO.searchController injection target must not be declared static.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:654 IST] 00000047 InjectionTarg W   CWNEN0057W: The com.ibm.gsar.dao.abb.AbbAssetDAO.gdaControllerLocal injection target must not be declared static.
[7/10/16 16:06:00:670 IST] 00000047 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the com.ibm.gsar.scheduler.DocumentReviewReminderTask class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TaskHandlerHome
[7/10/16 16:06:00:670 IST] 00000047 InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the com.ibm.gsar.scheduler.SchedulerContext class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Scheduler
[7/10/16 16:06:00:685 IST] 00000047 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the com.ibm.gsar.scheduler.SchedulerContext class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TaskStatus
[7/10/16 16:06:00:685 IST] 00000047 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the com.ibm.gsar.scheduler.SchedulerServiceLocator class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Scheduler
[7/10/16 16:06:00:685 IST] 00000047 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the com.ibm.gsar.scheduler.SchedulerTask class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TaskHandlerHome
[7/10/16 16:06:00:701 IST] 00000047 BeansDeployer E   PassivationCapable bean id is not unique: MANAGER#interface javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager#@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(),@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), bean:BeanManager, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGER, API Types:[javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]
                                 org.apache.webbeans.exception.definition.DuplicateDefinitionException: PassivationCapable bean id is not unique: MANAGER#interface javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager#@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(),@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), bean:BeanManager, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGER, API Types:[javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.addPassivationInfo(BeanManagerImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.addInternalBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:157)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:157)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.WebBeansInitializer.onStartup(WebBeansInitializer.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2486)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6463)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

[7/10/16 16:06:00:763 IST] 00000047 IncidentImpl  I   FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "org.apache.webbeans.exception.definition.DuplicateDefinitionException: PassivationCapable bean id is not unique: MANAGER#interface javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager#@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(),@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), bean:BeanManager, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGER, API Types:[javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default] com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_16.07.10_16.06.00.0.log
```

FFDC Log

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [7/10/16 16:06:00:732 IST]
Exception = org.apache.webbeans.exception.definition.DuplicateDefinitionException
Source = com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost
probeid = startWebApp
Stack Dump = org.apache.webbeans.exception.definition.DuplicateDefinitionException: PassivationCapable bean id is not unique: MANAGER#interface javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager#@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(),@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), bean:BeanManager, Name:null, WebBeans Type:MANAGER, API Types:[javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.addPassivationInfo(BeanManagerImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.addInternalBean(BeanManagerImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:157)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:157)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.WebBeansInitializer.onStartup(WebBeansInitializer.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2486)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6463)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

Comment: Have you tried addressing any of the warnings / NCDFEs?

Comment: these warning are only coming when I add cdi in my project facet. if don't add cdi in my project facet it works fine without the injection feature.

Answer (score 1):

You have cross posted this on IBM DeveloperWorks, which several of us have answered your questions.

This is most likely do to a configuration conflict. Try enabling the features cdi-1.2 and jsf-2.2, and you should be using @Named and not @ManagedBean.

Answer (score 0):

The FFDC here is saying that you have a duplicate field somewhere.  Without seeing more of your project, it seems likely there's some issue with the mixing of JSF and CDI injection here.  For example, you're using @ManagedBean on the code snippet, while trying to leverage CDI injection (@Named) elsewhere.  A good starting point may be to convert your JSF-injected beans to CDI-injected beans.

[Discussion on JSF vs CDI injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062859/3864977)